# Append value to dataframe in the same row but different columns with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with pandas.

I created different dataframes and for each of them defined the columns:

```
for delay_index in range(len(delays)):
    with open(f'Delay_'+str(delay_index)+'.txt','w+'):
        df[delay_index] = pd.DataFrame()
        df[delay_index] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Field'] + [f'{name}_I0' for name in peak_names])
```

After that i do some fitting with lmfit and I try to store the fitted values in the dataframes as follow calling the values from the result of the fit:

```
for delay_index in range(len(delays)):
        df[delay_index]=df[delay_index].append({'Field':b}, ignore_index=True)
    
        for name in peak_names:
            param_name = f'{name}_I_{delay_index}'
            df[delay_index] = df[delay_index].append({f'{name}_I0':result.params[param_name].value}, 
ignore_index=True)
```

Then I write out:

```
for delay_index in range(len(delays)):
    df[delay_index].to_csv(f'Delay_{delay_index}.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

The problem I am facing is that each time I update the dataframe it appends the new value on a different row ending up with a result like this:

```
Field   p1_I0   p2_I0   p3_I0   p4_I0
709.97              
    2149603.9483728814          
        2304388.805528784       
            2803053.0849080454  
                2985452.31396472
498.88              
    2052931.2878375147          
        2200678.495335952       
            2682353.9101734087  
                2839037.5609275587
```

while ideally i would like to have it like this:

```
Field   p1_I0   p2_I0   p3_I0   p4_I0
709.97  2149603.9483728814  2304388.805528784   2803053.0849080454  2985452.31396472
498.88  2052931.2878375147  2200678.495335952   2682353.9101734087  2839037.5609275587
```

Do you have a solution on how to get the values in the same row?
I am a beginner so I apologize if I could not phrase the question in a more clear way.

Thank you!

I tried to look in various forum and if the question had been answered before but i could not find an answer. It seems like everytime I call the append() function it updates the row counting.

---

UPDATE

I solved it in the following way:

```
>     for delay_index in range(len(delays)):
        i=int(expno.index(num))
        df[delay_index].at[i, 'Field'] = b
    
        for name in peak_names:
            param_name = f'{name}_I_{delay_index}'
            df[delay_index].at[i, f'{name}_I0'] = result.params[param_name].value
```

I defined an index for the row and then use 'at' to append the value at the indexed row and defined column.

Thanks Laurent for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reproducible example, so it is difficult to know how to refactor your code, but here is an example of how to deal with your current result.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, "", 2, ""], "col2": ["", 3, "", 4]})

print(df)
# Output
   col1  col2
0     1      
1           3
2     2      
3           4
```

Then, using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[col].replace("", pd.NA).dropna(how="any").reset_index(drop=True)
        for col in df.columns
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(new_df)
# Output
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```